# Issue with initializing ArcObjects Interface and classes

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, .net, add-in

I was going through ArcObjects example on following link[Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/) .I followed same steps but I was getting error while initializing objects for following code.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRubberBand rubberBand = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberLineClass()
ISimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleMarkerSymbolClass()
IMarkerElement markerElement = new MarkerElementClass()
```

etc I was not able to find exact reason why I was getting but may be due to version of ArcObjects.I am using .Net 4.0,Visual studio 2010, ArcObjects 10.2.
I got following type of error

```
The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberLineClass' has no constructors defined.
Interop type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleMarkerSymbolClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
```

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting? Could you provide more information?

Comment: Are you trying to run this as an add-in or a standalone application? Have you referenced your assemblies, both with assembly reference and imports?

Comment: Error Message like these `The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RubberLineClass' has no constructors defined`   `Interop type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleMarkerSymbolClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead`

Comment: @JasonScheirer I have added few error message

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I am getting these error at compile time and these are addin type of  application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem in Visual Studio 2010, when you included your error message it came back to me. The answer can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded.

Extract of:

*For whatever reason, this assembly can't be embedded - but it sounds like that's not a problem for you. Just open the Properties tab for the assembly in Visual Studio 2010 and set "Embed Interop Types" to "False".*

Answer (score 0):

Same type of problem comes when use AoInitializeClass

Interop type 'AoInitializeClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

for solve issue use following steps.

1. Goo to in Solution Explorer.
2. Right click on project Properties.
3. Change References ESRI.ArcGIS.System set 'Embed Interop Types' to 'false'